# SQL select rows conditionally using CASE expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm practicing some SQL and I have to retrieve from the database all the information about employees whose (sal+comm) > 1700. I know this can be done with a simple WHERE expression, but we are practicing the CASE statement, so we need to do it that way.

I already know how regular CASE works to assign a new row values dependending on other row values, but I don't understand how to select rows depending on a condition using a CASE expression.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (sal+comm) > 1700 THEN empno
    END AS empno
FROM emp;
```

I know it's wrong, but I'm stucked here. Any help or any resources to search and read about would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE (CASE WHEN (sal+comm) > 1700 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

the `CASE` statement will produce a result and you can compare it or use it on other operations.

In this case the salary depend on emp.job

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE CASE WHEN emp.job = 'DEVELOPER' THEN salary*1.5
           WHEN emp.job = 'DB' THEN salary*2
      END > 1700
```

To solve your case is overkill but I guess you can include other cases.

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE CASE WHEN sal+comm > 1700 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END > 0
```

Answer (score -4):

You want a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT empNo
FROM emp
WHERE sal+comm > 1700
```

Comment: @Elias specifically said that he knows how to do it in a simple `WHERE` clause, but wants to practice with `CASE`